# Based on what value user select for dropdownlist, insert that id of that value to the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, insert, dropdownbox

I have two tables which is appointment and medicalcentre which have relationship with each other using mcID. For my appointment form, i populate the dropdownlist to display the McCentre field of medicalcentre table. And what I want to do is to, based on what the user select for the McCentre in the dropdownlist, and submit the form, the appropiate mcID of MedicalCentre table will be inserted into the appointment table. etc, If I select Sliver Cross Family Clinic and submit the form, the appointment table will insert a new record of mcID 4. Because based on medicalcentre table, sliver cross family clinic belongs to mcID 4.

For the below codes that i posted. After choosing mcCentre (Hwang & Liang Family Clinic) and clicking sign up button, I got (Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Hwang & Liang Family Clinic' to data type int.)   Help?

**APPOINTMENT FORM**

[image]

**APPOINTMENT AND MEDICALCENTRE TABLES**
[image]

Error following hutchonoid code

[image]

Error following hutchonoid code 2

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class appointment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();

            //SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from MEDICALCENTRE", con); // table name 
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select mcCentre from MEDICALCENTRE", con); // table name 
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset
            //ddlMedicalCentre.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["mcID"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
            //ddlMedicalCentre.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["mcID"].ToString();             // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlMedicalCentre.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["mcCentre"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
            ddlMedicalCentre.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["mcCentre"].ToString();             // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlMedicalCentre.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
            ddlMedicalCentre.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist
        }
    }
    protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    Guid guid;
                    guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                    String strStatus = "waiting";
                    string sql = "INSERT INTO appointment (aStatus,aDate, aTime, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, patientID, mcID)";
                    sql += "VALUES (@aStatus, @aDate, @aTime, @aContact, @aHeight, @aWeight, @patientID, @mcID)";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aStatus", strStatus);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aDate", txtDate.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aTime", txtTime.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aContact", txtContact.Value.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aHeight", txtHeight.Value.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aWeight", txtWeight.Value.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientID", ID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcID", Convert.ToInt16(ddlMedicalCentre.SelectedValue.Trim()));

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    con.Open();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                   // Session.Add("Username", txtFirstName.Value);
                  //  Session.Add("Password", txtContact.Value);
                  //  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtFirstName.Value, true);
                    Response.Redirect("../index.aspx");

                }

                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks ok to me at first glance. Are there any errors?

Comment: After choosing mcCentre (Hwang & Liang Family Clinic) and clicking sign up button, I got (Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Hwang & Liang Family Clinic' to data type int.) @hutchonoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the selected value from a `string` to an `Int`.

This returns a string:

```
  ddlMedicalCentre.SelectedValue.Trim()
```

And the statement is expecting an `Int`.

This will fix the issue:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcID", Convert.ToInt16(ddlMedicalCentre.SelectedValue.Trim()));
```

**Update**

You need to make sure that your dropdown list is using the Id as the value like this:

```
 ddlMedicalCentre.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["mcId"].ToString();
```

and **not** this which is setting the text to the value:

```
 ddlMedicalCentre.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["mcCentre"].ToString();
```

You should leave DataTextField as is though to display the name.

**Update 2**

Copy this into a new method i.e.

```
private void BindMedicalDropdowns()
        {

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();

            //SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from MEDICALCENTRE", con); // table name 
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select mcCentre from MEDICALCENTRE", con); // table name 
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset
            //ddlMedicalCentre.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["mcID"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
            //ddlMedicalCentre.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["mcID"].ToString();             // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlMedicalCentre.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["mcCentre"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
            ddlMedicalCentre.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["mcCentre"].ToString();             // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlMedicalCentre.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
            ddlMedicalCentre.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist
        }
```

Then move it out of the !IsPostBack clause so it gets re-bound on postback too.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindMedicalDropdowns();
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

    }   
}
```

**Update 3**

On line 32, your select statement should be this, it's missing the `mcID` field:

```
select mcId, mcCentre from MEDICALCENTRE
```

Comment: Now I got this man. Input string was not in a correct format. @hutchonoid

Comment: What is SQL like before u execute? Can u add it to your question so I can take a look?

Comment: U mean my updated codes right? i edited above, and add a image. I;m going out now, i will come back later to check, thank man. @hutchonoid.

Comment: oh I'm new here. I did tick answers whenever somebody solve my question. but my question is not solve yet. I wonder why should I tick before its not solve? and creating new thread/question. wont the system warn me about duplicates?   I'm using my phone to reply u since I am out now haha. @hutchonoid

Comment: No, the question has moved. Your original question was regarding the cast of the Int. That was solved and it has moved to something else now. The question has became a moving target.

Comment: so its ok if I use the same title and descriptiom except that I need to just change my error to the current one right @hutchonoid

Comment: @Jordjmax Hi, it's ok. I'll just continue with this one for now to save you. Just to make you aware though as you will get more responses if you split questions out, if that makes sense. I've added an update that will hopefully fix your issue. Give that a go and we should be sorted. Good luck. :)

Comment: Opps, look like its not solve yet lol. Error. I will it as a new question then.. @hutchonoid

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46445/discussion-between-hutchonoid-and-jordjmax)

Comment: No error, and a mcID is inserted to the database after clicking signup, but the problem is it always gives me mcID of 1 whatever mcCentre that I choose in the dropdownlist. Guess I need to create another thread @hutchonoid

Comment: Nice one. If you do another question, tag the link to this and i'll take a look if I'm online. :)